# Whats the equivalent of Pandas.apply() in Agate

Tags: pandas, apply

I am using dbt in the which the out of result_query statement is an Agate table. I need to transform a column in this table and want to know the equivalent of apply function of pandas in Agate.

Comment: Hi, Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's very hard to understand and help you without sample reproducible input(s) and expected output(s).

Comment: Please be more specific! One idea is that if you tansformation uses a by you defined function, you could use ```compute``` and ```Formula``` in the following manner:
```def  <your function>``` and your transformation ```new_table = table.compute([('<the column to transform>', Formula(output_dtype, <your function>))])```. Here you need to defined the output_dtype (e.g. ```output_dtypee = agate.Number()```)